# Hide buttons in form view when link is different

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

Consider a Path

Patient -> selected Patient -> Prescriptions -> New

On that path there's a prescription form, in that form there are two buttons "button 1" and "button 2", now i want to these two buttons when Path is like that

Patient -> selected Patient -> New

Now i am able to open new Prescription form on button click using code like that

```
def goto_prescription_form(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

  return {

         'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',

         'name': 'Reffer Patient to Physician',

         'res_model': 'oeh.medical.prescription',

         'view_type': 'form',

         'view_mode': 'form',

   }
```

Comment: Python is very expressive language. You can implement things in any form you like. I think you can do:
`if(path_is_like_that()):
   button_from_str("button 1").do_like_that("Patient -> selected Patient -> New ")` 
Apply the same to the second button. It should work.

Comment: and what should be the body of "path_is_like_that()" function, i need to detect path in odoo

Comment: @AhmedKhakwani you want to hide default buttons 'create/cancel'? Is it right?

Comment: No i need to hide two buttons which are created in form like that "<button string='like-that' type='object'>", so i need to hide that button when path is like "Patient -> selected Patient -> New" and i do not want to hide button when link path is like that "Patient -> selected Patient -> Prescriptions -> New"